# Trying to get post from the OMDb API by retrofit but error says URL query string must not have replace block

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I'm trying to get movie plot, or release year through the OMDb API. When I type a movie name I get this error message:

```
URL query string must not have replace block
```

I changed the call method in the interface instead of the path to query:

```
@GET("?t={id}&apikey=apikey(that's private)")
Call<Post> getPost(@Query("id") String name);
```

But I get the same error message.

Here is my code.

MainActivity

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView tvText;

Retrofit retrofit;
ApiInterface apiInterface;
Call<Post> call;

EditText editText;
Button getButton;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

tvText=findViewById(R.id.tvText);
editText=findViewById(R.id.editText);
getButton=findViewById(R.id.getButton);


} 

public void get(View view) {

retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("http://www.omdbapi.com/")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build();

apiInterface = retrofit.create(ApiInterface.class);

call = apiInterface.getPost(editText.getText().toString());

call.enqueue(new Callback<Post>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<Post> call, Response<Post> response) {
        tvText.setText(response.body().getPlot());

    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<Post> call, Throwable t) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

});
}
 }
```

Interface:

```java
public interface ApiInterface {

@GET("?t={id}&apikey=apikey(that's private)")
Call<Post> getPost(@Path("id") String name);
}
```

`Post` class for JSON keys:

```java
public class Post {

private int Year;
private String Plot;
private String Title;


public int getYear() {
return Year;
}

public String getPlot() {
return Plot;
}

public String getTitle() {
return Title;
}
}
```

XML

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res        /android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
android:id="@+id/tvText"
android:layout_width="324dp"
android:layout_height="92dp"
android:layout_marginTop="72dp"
android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.535"
app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText" />

<EditText
android:id="@+id/editText"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
android:layout_marginTop="88dp"
android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
android:ems="10"
android:inputType="textPersonName"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.503"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
android:id="@+id/getButton"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
android:clickable="true"
android:onClick="get"
android:text="get"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvText" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `t={id}` from annotation and use query param name directly in  `@Query` like this:

```
@GET("?apikey=apikey(that's private)")
Call<Post> getPost(@Query("t") String id);
```